# Monad laws expressed in terms of join instead of bind?

Tags: haskell, monads

The monad laws are traditionally described in terms of `>>=` and `pure`:

```
pure a >>= k = k a
m >>= pure = m
m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h) = (m >>= k) >>= h
```

However, monads can also be defined in terms of `join` instead of `>>=`. I would like to come up with a formulation of the monad laws in terms of `join`.

Using `x >>= f = join (fmap f x)`, it’s easy to rewrite the existing monad laws to eliminate `>>=`. Simplifying the results slightly with the help of the applicative laws, the first two laws are quite pleasantly expressed:

```
join . pure = id
join . fmap pure = id
```

The intuition for these laws is easy, too, since clearly, introducing an extra “layer” with `pure` should be a no-op when combined with `join`. The third law, however, is not nearly so nice. It ends up looking like this:

```
  join (fmap (\x -> join (fmap h (k x))) m)
= join (fmap h (join (fmap k m)))
```

This does not pleasantly reduce using the applicative laws, and it’s much harder to understand without staring at it for a while. It certainly doesn’t have the same easy intuition.

Is there an equivalent, alternative formulation of the monad laws in terms of `join` that is easier to understand? Alternatively, is there any way to simplify the above law, or to make it easier to grok? The version with `>>=` is already less nice than the one expressed with Kleisli composition, but the version with `join` is nearly unreadable.

Comment: If such terse mathematical language is accessible to you, I think [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) is a clear definition. Basically, the left-hand diagram corresponds to the first two laws you've stated (`join . pure = join . fmap pure = id`) and the right-hand diagram can be stated as `join . join = join . fmap join`. Note that `(\h k m -> join (fmap h (join (fmap k m)))) id id = \m -> join (join m)` - this follows from `fmap id = id` (and likewise for the other side of the two equalities). In other words, your law expresses both functor and monad laws in one statement.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Stolen straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition):

(The natural transformation `η: 1 -> T` is `pure`; the natural transformation `µ: T^2 -> T` is `join`)

> `µ . Tµ = µ . µT`

In Haskell:

```
join . fmap join = join . join
```

In English: If you start with three layers of monad as `mmma :: Monad m => m (m (m a))`, it doesn't matter if you flatten it inner layer first and then outer, or flatten it outer layer first and then inner. This is the same law as what you listed as the third (associativity).

> `µ . Tη = µ . ηT = 1`

In Haskell:

`join . fmap pure = join . pure = id`

In English: If you start with one layer of monad as `ma :: Monad m => m a`, it doesn't matter if you create a new layer inside it and then flatten it, or if you create a new layer outside it and then flatten it, and both are the same as doing nothing at all. This law is a combination of your first two.

Also, `join` being a natural transformation means that

`join . fmap (fmap f) = fmap f . join`

because of parametricity.

Comment: With your English explanation, I think I actually prefer these laws to the Kleisli composition version.

Comment: You're missing one law: `join . fmap (fmap f) ≡ fmap f . join`

Comment: @Shersh That's implied by `join` being a natural transformation. A natural transformation is `f: F -> G` must have `f . F(m) = G(m) . f` for all morphisms `m`.

Comment: All this is really good... But I can't see how to derive this law from other two laws in your question. The origin question is about Monad laws in terms of join so it's quite reasonable to see all laws for Monad. It's just the fact that not every person knows Category Theory but this person may google "Monad laws in terms of join" and won't find all laws.

Comment: @Shersh You derive it from it's type. Any definition of `join` that typechecks (and doesn't cheat with bottom) obeys that law. You can edit it in if you feel like it, but make a note that it is automatically true.

Comment: But this law can't be derived from other laws. I don't understand what it means to derive from type... It's not clear for me, how one person can look at type class `class Functor m => MonadJoin m where` in Haskell and automatically come up with all laws for this type class.

Comment: `join :: forall m a. Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` (`join` is indexed by `m` and is parametric in `a`). Parametric types give rise to theorems. In particular, if `Functor f, g`, then for any `r :: forall a. f a -> g a`, the type tells you that `r . fmap @f k = fmap @g k . r` for all `k`. In the case of `join`, `g = m` and `f = m . m`, so `fmap @f k = fmap @m (fmap @m k)` and you get the law `join . (fmap (fmap k)) = fmap k . join` This law is therefore implied by the type of `join` and is checked by the typechecker. https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf

Comment: @Shersh [1/2] HTNW's explanation is appropriate. `join . fmap (fmap f) ≡ fmap f . join` isn't usually taken as a monad law, as it follows from parametricity and/or naturality (a typical presentation goes like this: "`join` and `return` are natural transformations that obey the following three laws..."). If you allow me an unsubstantiated guess, I suspect you might have been thinking of either of the following two passages...

Comment: [2/2] ...from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join) and the [Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#The_third_and_fourth_laws), which confusingly add `join . fmap (fmap f) ≡ fmap f . join` as a law (and even, in the Wikibook, talk about a "fourth law"). With respect to the Wikibook, [I have been aware of this problem for quite a while](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:Haskell/Category_theory#Second_monad_law), but have been continuously procrastinating a rewrite of the relevant section -- shame on me... :P

Comment: @duplode I've edited this into the body of the answer; but it got me thinking: the "fourth Monad law" is guaranteed by `join` being a natural transformation, but what's the guarantee for a given monad's `join` to be natural transformation? so maybe this condition, that `join` is natural transformation, itself becomes the fourth monad law?

Comment: @WillNess `join . fmap (fmap f) ≡ fmap f . join` is itself saying that `join` is a natural transformation -- one from the Hask endofunctor `Compose m m` to the Hask endofunctor `m`. The guarantee that it holds is given by parametricity.