# What is the mathematical theory or theorem underlying join of monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

For example:

```
Maybe (Maybe Bool) -> Maybe Bool    
    
Just (Just True) -----> Just True     
Just (Just False) ----> Just False    
Just (Nothing) -------> Nothing    
Nothing --------------> ?
```

It would map `Nothing` to `Nothing`. What is the mathematical theory or theorem underlying it?
If related to category theory, what part is it related to?

Is there a mathematical theory related to the Behavior of join of State, Writer, Reader, etc?

Is there any guarantee that `m(m a) -> m a` is safe?

edited:

Since result type `a` of `m a -> a` forgets the structure. so instead in order not to forget, result type `m a` of `m (m a) -> m a` is used for the compound effect of `outer - m (...)` with effect of `inner - m`.

Strictly speaking, two information(effect) was compounded into one only before **the structure disappeared**. The structure no longer exists.

I thought it was important to guarantee that there was no problem in doing so. Is it up to the programmer without any special rules or theory?

The compound doesn't look natural to me, it looks artificial.
Sorry for the vague question, thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Most texts of Monad tell you why this function is needed, but not why this function is possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition : it is the mu part:  μ : T^2 → T

Comment: I wonder how two effects are compounded are safe, mu part tells me T^2 -> T type is needed.

Comment: There are two different `Nothing` values involved: one has type `Maybe (Maybe Bool)`, the other `Maybe Bool`. Both are specialized from the polymorphic value `Nothing :: Maybe a`.

Comment: What does "safe" mean to you?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner If I map `Nothing :: m m` to `Just False :: m`, I expect that I have broken some rules.

Comment: What sort of rules do you mean when you say *"Is it up to the programmer without any special rules?"*? There are laws given for `Monad`s in the documentation and `join` is implemented (in Haskell) using `(>>=)` from `Monad`. Are those laws the sort of rules you mean or do you mean a different kind of rule?

Comment: @LionhairdinoL.: There can be multiple possible instances of `Monad` for a type, but some might not be very useful/interesting. But in your case, you can’t actually map `Nothing` to `Just False`. Let me abbreviate `M` = `Maybe`, `J` = `Just`, `N` = `Nothing`. There are only two functions of type `forall a. M (M a) -> M a`, namely `\case { J (J x) -> J x; J N -> N; N -> N; }` and `\case { J (J x) -> N; J N -> N; N -> N; }`. The latter isn’t a valid `join` if `pure = Just`. It obeys associativity `join . join` = `join . fmap join` but not identity `join . pure` = `join . fmap pure` = `id`.

Comment: I think you may be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/45829110/869736: the rules that `join` is required to follow.

Comment: You are *not* defining `join` to turn `Nothing :: m m` to `Just False :: m`. You must turn `Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a))` into some value of type `Maybe a`, with the same `a`, *whatever that `a` might be*. No specific type for `a`, like `Bool`, ever comes into play when defining a `Monad` instance for `Maybe`, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Mathematical definition of a monad, with translation to Haskell:

### A couple of incidental preliminary notes

I'm going to assume you're familiar with Functors in Haskell. If not I'm tempted to direct you to my explanation on this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137359/1598537). I'm not going to explain category theory to you except by translating it into Haskell as best I can.

**Identity functor vs `Identity` `Functor` instance.**

Note: Firstly let me point out that the identity functor in mathematics does nothing, whereas the `Identity` functor in Haskell adds a newtype wrapper. Whenever we use the mathematical identity functor on a type `a` we should just get `a` back, so I won't be using the `Identity` functor instance.

**Natural transformations**

Secondly, note that a natural transformation between two functors (either possibly the identity), in Haskell is a polymorphic function `e` between two types made by (possibly mathematical identity) Functor instances, for example `[a] -> Maybe a` or `(Int,a) -> Either String a` such that `e . fmap f` == `fmap f . e`.

So `safeLast : [a] -> Maybe a` is a natural transformation, because `safeLast (map f xs)` == `fmap f (safeLast xs)`, and even

```
rejectSomeSmallNumbers :: (Int,a) -> Either String a
rejectSomeSmallNumbers (i,a) = case i of
   0 -> Left "Way too small!"
   1 -> Left "Too small!"
   2 -> Left "Two is small."
   3 -> Left "Three is small, too."
   _ -> Right a
```

is a natural transformation because `rejectSomeSmallNumbers . fmap f` == `fmap f . rejectSomeSmallNumbers :: (Int,a) -> Either String b`.

A natural transformation can use as much information as it likes about the two functors it connects (eg `(,) Int` and `Either String`) but it can't use any information about the type `a` any more than the functors can. It shouldn't be possible to write a polymorphic function between two valid functor types that's not a natural transformation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58363868/1598537) for more information.

### What is a monad according to Maths and Haskell?

*Let H be a category* (let Hask be the kind of all haskell types together with function types, functions, etc etc).

*A monad on H is* (a monad in Hask is)

- *an endofunctor `M : H -> H`*

  - a type constructor `m: * -> *` which has a Functor instance with `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`
- and *a natural transformation `eta : 1_H -> M`*

  - a polymorphic function from `a -> m a`, called `pure` defined in the `Applicative` instance
- *a natural transformation `mu : M^2 -> M`*

  - a polymorphic function from `m (m a) -> m a`, called `join` that is defined in `Control.Monad`

such that the following two rules hold:

- *`mu . M mu == mu . mu M` as natural transformations `M^3 -> M`*

  - `join . fmap join` == `join . join` :: `m (m (m a)) -> m a`
- *`mu . M eta` == `mu . eta M` == `1_H` as natural transformations `M -> M`*

  - `join . fmap pure` == `join . pure` == `id` :: `m a -> m a`

**What do these two rules mean?**

Just to give you a handle on what these two conditions are saying, here they are when we're using lists:

```
(join . fmap join) [xss, yss, zss] 
== join [join xss, join yss, join zss] 
== join (join [xss, yss, zss])
```

and

```
join (fmap pure xs)
 == join [[x] | x <- xs]
 == xs
 == id xs
 == join [xs]
 == join (pure xs)
```

(Fun fact, `join` isn't part of the monad definition. I have a perhaps unreliable memory that it used to be, but in `Control.Monad` it's defined as `join x = x >>= id` and as commented there, it could be defined as `join bss = do { bs <- bss ; bs }`)

### What does this mean for the `Maybe` monad in your example?

Well firstly, because `join` is polymorphic (*`mu`* is a natural transformation), it can't use any information about the type `a` in `Maybe a`, so we couldn't for example make it so that `join (Just (Just False)) = Just True` or `join (Just Nothing) = Just False` because we can only use values that are already in the `Maybe a` we're given:

```
join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join Nothing = Nothing          -- can't provide Just a because we have no a
join (Just Nothing) = Nothing   -- same reason
join (Just (Just a)) =                 
    -- two choices: we could do the obviously correct `Just a` or collapse everything with `Nothing`.

pure :: a -> Maybe a
pure a =                               
        -- two choices: we could do the obviously correct `Just a` or collapse everything with `Nothing`.
```

What stops us doing the crazy `Nothing` thing?

Let's look at the two rules, specialising to `Maybe`, and to the `Just` branches, because all the `Nothing`s are inevitably `Nothing` because of polymorphism.

```
(join . fmap join) (Just maybemaybe) 
== join (Just (join maybemaybe)) 
== join (join (Just maybemaybe)) -- required by he rule
```

That one works if we put `Just a` in the definition, or if we put `Nothing`, too.

In the second rule:

```
join (fmap pure (Just a))
 == join (Just (pure a))
 == join (pure (Just a))
 == id (Just a)           -- by the rule
 == Just a
```

Well that forces `pure` to be `Just`, and at the same time forces `join (Just (Just a))` to give us `Just a`.

### Reader

Let's ditch the newtype wrapping to make the laws easier to talk about.

```
type Reader input a = input -> a
```

We'd need

```
join :: Reader input (Reader input a) -> Reader input a
join (make_an_a_maker :: (input -> (input -> a)) :: input -> a
join make_an_a_maker input = (make_an_a_maker input) input
```

There isn't anything else we can do without using `undefined` or similar.

### So what stops you making crazy `join` functions?

Most of the time, the fact that you're making a polymorphic function, some of the time because you want to do the obviously correct thing and it works, and the rest of the time because you chose to follow the rules.

#### Not-relevant nerd note:

I prefer to think of Monads as type constructors `m` so that `Kleisli` composition is associative, with the unit being `pure`:

```
(>=>) :: (a -> m b) 
      -> (       b -> m c)
      -> (a -> m        c)
(first >=> second) a = do
    b <- first a
    c <- second b
    return c
```

or if you prefer

```
(first >=> second) a =
  first a >>= \b -> second b
```

so the laws are

- `(one >=> two) >=> three` == `one >=> (two >=> three)` and
- `k >=> pure` == `pure >=> k` == `k`

Comment: Giving these specific examples of natural transformations is very helpful, thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, @WillNess, how delightful to interact with you again after all these years! Thank you for tidying things up for me. You've always been good at improving my posts.

Comment: same here. :) you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is over the fact that `Nothing` is not a single value. It is a polymorphic type that can be specialized to any number of values, depending on how `a` is fixed:

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> :t Nothing
Nothing :: Maybe a
> :t Nothing @Int
Nothing @Int :: Maybe Int
> :t Nothing @Bool
Nothing @Bool :: Maybe Bool
> :t Nothing @(Maybe Bool)
Nothing @(Maybe Bool) :: Maybe (Maybe Bool)
```

Similarly, `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` can be specialized:

```
> :t join @Maybe
join @Maybe :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
> :t join @Maybe @Bool
join @Maybe @Bool :: Maybe (Maybe Bool) -> Maybe Bool
```

`Maybe (Maybe Bool)` has four values:

1. `Just (Just True)`
2. `Just (Just False)`
3. `Just Nothing`
4. `Nothing`

`Maybe Bool` has three values:

1. `Just True`
2. `Just False`
3. `Nothing`

`join :: Maybe (Maybe Bool)` is not a injection; it maps two different values of type `Maybe (Maybe Bool)` to the same value of type `Maybe Bool`:

```
join (Just (Just True)) == Just True
join (Just (Just False)) == Just False
join (Just Nothing) == Nothing
join Nothing == Nothing
```

Both `Just Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe Bool)` and `Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe Bool)` are mapped to `Nothing :: Maybe Bool`.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer I want.  I know that two effects are compounded. `m (m a)` has a two-layered structure but `m a` has only one layer. The two differ depending on the perspective. If there is a procedure that you have to do every time you peel off the `m`, the two may be different.

Comment: @LionhairdinoL. Maybe this will help: Consider the case where `m` is the list type constructor. Does `join` make sense for you in this situation? If so, you can think of `Maybe` as a "list" which can either have exactly one element or exactly zero elements.